# How to call more than one function in another function in C

Tags: c, iteration

I am trying to find out how it is possible to call different functions in different iterations in another function in C language. For example, suppose that the functions that I am doing the calling is A. In the first iteration I want to call function B in A but in all other iterations I want to call function C. Note that the iterations is not only on function A which is a part of a larger program so I can not put a for loop in this function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a locally-scoped static variable to keep track of if A has already been called:

```
void caller()
{
    static int called_before = 0;

    if (called_before)
    {
      B();
    }
    else
    {
      A();
      called_before = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function why not use a counter?:

```
static int count ;

if(count==0)
{
//call function B
}
else
{
//call function C
}
count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking requires some sort of state to be stored that is associated with and accessible to the function A.

The default state would indicate that the function has never been called, and then on the first call the function would check the state, see that it hasn't been called, and the change the state to indicate that it's been called, and then call function B.

All of the subsequent calls to A would check the state, see that it's been called, and call function C.

See the memento pattern for an explanation of maintaining state: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

Both @itsme86 and @brokenfoot have examples of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using a global variable.

In a header called header_global.h put the following:

```
extern int GlobalVar=0;
```

and then in your function put

#include "header_global.h"

```
 if (GlobalVar==0)
    {
      function_B();
      GlobalVar++;
    }
    else
    {
      function_C();
    }
```